# drawing views overlaid on an ImageView

Tags: android, drawing, view

I am trying to draw some TextViews overlaid on an ImageView, at the location where the user touches the image (similar to Instagram, when touching an image, and the tags appear as small popups with arrows at different positions).

I tried some simple tests using FrameLayout with ImageView and creating TextView with custom set margins and layout params. But I came across some issues (like getWidth and getHeight return 0 even though the TextView is added in his parent).

I would like to know what components or what external library could be best suited for this kind of "drawing"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no any perfect library for this type drawing but you can achieve this using Canvas Custome Drawing.
Like ,  If you want to draw some fixed typed text on Any Image then
1.take Source Image as Bitmap and set it in Canvas Object

```
    Bitmap sourceBitmap  = yourImageBitmap;
Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(soureBitmap);
```

Now you can draw text on that canvas 
 mCanvas.drawText(text,paint);

2. and then aftet you can take save your sourceBitmap as final bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

after searching some library I got this library for photo editing.
I have used this and work fine. Please Try this.
https://github.com/burhanrashid52/PhotoEditor